# Mocking a URL in Java

Tags: java, url, mocking

We have a URL object in one of our Java classes that we want to mock, but it's a final class so we cannot. We do not want to go a level above, and mock the InputStream because that will still leave us with untested code (we have draconian test coverage standards).

I've tried jMockIt's reflective powers but we work on Macs and there are problems with the Java agent handler that I haven't been able to resolve.

So are there any solutions that do not involve using real URLs in the junit test?

Comment: (java.net.URI is preferred over URL.)

Comment: Tom Hawtin: agreed, I got marked down for assuming the URL instance was some custom implementation. Please be more explicit next time - java.net.URL is easy enough to write.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I have a class that can't be easily mocked because it is final (or sealed in C#), my usual route is to write a wrapper around the class and use the wrapper wherever I would use the actual class.  Then I would mock out the wrapper class as necessary.

Comment: Yes but then I need to unit test the wrapper, with the URL class inside, and the problem persists.

Comment: No.  The wrapper is really thin and just reflects the methods on URL.  You shouldn't need to unit test it, you should be able to verify it by inspection.

Comment: Hmm, yes this is true. As I said above, it's that we have quite draconian coverage standards, and I would need to except the wrapper from our coverage. But this is the initial solution we came up with and I guess it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: "quite draconian coverage standards" - code coverage is a negative metric, meaning that it only tells useful info when you *dont* have coverage. once you got coverage, it doesnt really tell you anything about the quality of the code. I.e., having coverage does not indicate well tested code. i suggest you try to change the draconian standards if you can.

Comment: This is marked as an accepted answer, is there an example of how you were able to write a wrapper and test the wrapper instead of `new URL`?

Answer (score 25):

Like Rob said, if what you want is to mock the connection returned from the URL, you can extend `URLStreamHandler`. For instance, with mockito:

```
final URLConnection mockUrlCon = mock(URLConnection.class);

ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        "<myList></myList>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
doReturn(is).when(mockUrlCon).getInputStream();

//make getLastModified() return first 10, then 11
when(mockUrlCon.getLastModified()).thenReturn((Long)10L, (Long)11L);

URLStreamHandler stubUrlHandler = new URLStreamHandler() {
    @Override
     protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
        return mockUrlCon;
     }            
};
URL url = new URL("foo", "bar", 99, "/foobar", stubUrlHandler);
doReturn(url).when(mockClassloader).getResource("pseudo-xml-path");
```

Answer (score 13):

I went with the following:

```
public static URL getMockUrl(final String filename) throws IOException {
    final File file = new File("testdata/" + filename);
    assertTrue("Mock HTML File " + filename + " not found", file.exists());
    final URLConnection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(URLConnection.class);
    given(mockConnection.getInputStream()).willReturn(
            new FileInputStream(file));

    final URLStreamHandler handler = new URLStreamHandler() {

        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL arg0)
                throws IOException {
            return mockConnection;
        }
    };
    final URL url = new URL("http://foo.bar", "foo.bar", 80, "", handler);
    return url;
}
```

This gives me a real URL object that contains my mock data.

Comment: Good answer! I did this too after trying with Powermock for 15 minutes

Comment: This is the only solution that actually worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to create a wrapper :

Register a URLStreamHandlerFactory

Make the method you want public

Mock the chain

```
abstract public class AbstractPublicStreamHandler extends URLStreamHandler {
    @Override
    public URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}

public class UrlTest {
    private URLStreamHandlerFactory urlStreamHandlerFactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        urlStreamHandlerFactory = Mockito.mock(URLStreamHandlerFactory.class);
        URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(urlStreamHandlerFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_mocked_url() throws Exception {
        // GIVEN
        AbstractPublicStreamHandler publicStreamHandler = Mockito.mock(AbstractPublicStreamHandler.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(publicStreamHandler).when(urlStreamHandlerFactory).createURLStreamHandler(Matchers.eq("http"));

        URLConnection mockedConnection = Mockito.mock(URLConnection.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(mockedConnection).when(publicStreamHandler).openConnection(Matchers.any(URL.class));

        Mockito.doReturn(new ByteArrayInputStream("hello".getBytes("UTF-8"))).when(mockedConnection).getInputStream();

        // WHEN
        URLConnection connection = new URL("http://localhost/").openConnection();

        // THEN
        Assertions.assertThat(new MockUtil().isMock(connection)).isTrue();
        Assertions.assertThat(IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")).isEqualTo("hello");
    }
}
```

PS : I don't know how to cancel the numbered list auto-spacing after last line

Comment: Based on your answer I wrote the following blog post: https://claritysoftware.co.uk/mocking-javas-url-with-mockito/

Comment: @NathanRussell great article! I've simplified it a bit and rewrote it in Kotlin https://gist.github.com/felipecsl/de84eae52172a4fdccef403f6810366c

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use Powermock to do this. I was able to mock URL class using PowerMock lately. Hope this helps.

/* Actual class */

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestClass {

    public URL getUrl()
        throws MalformedURLException {

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/");
        return url;
    }
}
```

/* Test class */

```
import java.net.URL;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = { TestClass.class })
public class TestClassTest {

    private TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnUrl()
        throws Exception {

        URL url = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withParameterTypes(String.class)
                .withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(url);
        URL url1 = testClass.getUrl();
        Assert.assertNotNull(url1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter can you help me here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031175/testing-powermock-simulate-http-server-time-out-for-client-call)

Comment: Its important, as you did mention, to use PowerMockito.mock and not Mockito.mock

Answer (score 6):

I have used a URLHandler that allows me to load a URL from the classpath.  So the following

```
new URL("resource:///foo").openStream()
```

would open a file named foo from within the class path.  To do this, I use a [common utility library](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/common-util/) and register a handler.  To use this handler, you just need to call:

```
com.healthmarketscience.common.util.resource.Handler.init();
```

and the resource URL is now available.

Comment: IMO, it's much better to use the URL constructor rather than mess with statics in the URL class.

Answer (score 3):

Create a URL-object pointing to the test class itself.

```
final URL url = 
    new URL("file://" + getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

Answer (score 2):

I would look again at why you *want* to mock a final data object.  Since by definition you aren't subclassing the object in your actual code, and it's not going to be the object under test, you shouldn't need to white-box test this code; just pass in whatever (real) URL objects are appropriate, and check the output.

Mock objects are useful when it's difficult to create a real object appropriate, or the real object's method are either time-consuming or depend on some stateful external resource (like a database).  Neither of these apply in this case so I can't see why you can't just construct a real URL object representing the appropriate resource location.

Comment: Sure, it's the desire to decouple the tests from a real url of any kind, and when we call openConnection we open a new dependency.

Comment: I think this is a legit problem.  Mocking frameworks shouldn't hide from these kinds of things...

Answer (score 2):

JMockit does indeed allow you to mock a final JRE class like java.net.URL.

It seems the Attach API in jdkDir/lib/tools.jar available in implementations of JDK 1.6 other than Sun's does not work as well. I guess this stuff is still too new/advanced, or simply didn't get the necessary attention from the other JDK vendors (Apple, IBM with the J9 JDK, Oracle with the JRockit JDK).

So, if you run into problems by having tools.jar in the classpath, try using the "-javaagent:jmockit.jar" JVM argument. It tells the JVM to directly load the java agent at startup, without using the Attach API. That should work in the Apple JDK 1.5/1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Does the URL class implement an interface? If so then you could instantiate it using inversion of control or a configurable factory, rather than by direct construction, this would allow you to inject/construct a test instance at test runtime rather than the final instance you currently have.

Comment: No as I said above URL is a final class, it's from the JDK.

Comment: OK, i read the questions  as "we have a URL object implemented by some final class (say MyURL, which for all I know could have an interface) rather than we have an instance of the java.net.URL class itself. I think the question could have been slightly more explicit.

Comment: Sure it could have been more explicit, it's a bit ambiguous as to whether it's a custom URL, apologies - but it still says it's final so...

Comment: something can be final and still implement an interface, lending itself to factory or injection construction.

Comment: I'm +1'ing this back - it shouldn't be -1 because you *could* create a factory to do the exact same thing your wrapper class (in the accepted answer) does.  Functionally equivalent, and what I would probably do if I had to take a first stab.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the constructor this way:

```
    new MockUp<URL>() {
        @Mock
        public void $init(Invocation invocation, String string) {
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerMockito for my case was the easiest solution. PowerMockito allows mocking static, final classes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper URL class in your test project:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UrlWrapper {
private URL url;

public UrlWrapper(String urlString) throws IOException {
    this.url = new URL(urlString);
}

public String getProtocol() {
    return url.getProtocol();
}

public String getHost() {
    return url.getHost();
}

public int getPort() {
    return url.getPort();
}
```

}

Then, use the wrapper like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class MyTest {

@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    UrlWrapper mockUrl = mock(UrlWrapper.class);
    when(mockUrl.getProtocol()).thenReturn("http");
    when(mockUrl.getHost()).thenReturn("www.example.com");
    when(mockUrl.getPort()).thenReturn(80);

    // Pass the mockUrl object to your method that uses a URL object
    // Assert the expected results
}
```

}