# JUnit Mockito URL and HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the following code:

```
public byte[] myFunction(String s1, String s2, String s3) {

    try {           
            URL myUrl = new URL("https://myUrl");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String lastPacket = connection.getHeaderField("LastPacket");

            byte fileContent[] = IOUtils.toByteArray((InputStream) connection.getInputStream());
            return fileContent;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to unit test the above code.
So I've written JUnit using MockitoJUnitRunner as:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EvmlSeviceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private URL url;

    @Mock
    private HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void preSetup() {
        try {
            Mockito.doReturn(httpsURLConnection).when(url).openConnection();
            Mockito.doReturn(200).when(httpsURLConnection).getResponseCode();
            Mockito.doReturn("-1").when(httpsURLConnection).getHeaderField("LastPacket");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyFunction() {
        myClass.myFunction("my", "dummy", "data");
    }
}
```

But the problem here is that URL is final class and Mockito cannot spy final classes. Since we're using MockitoJUnitRunner, how can this be done?

I'm getting the exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot mock/spy class
>   java.net.URL

Comment: Mock the final class as you mock any other, what is the problem, explain in specific.

Comment: I have mocked the final class URL, as seen in the above code. I'm getting exception: `Cannot mock/spy class java.net.URL`

Comment: You are using Mockito 2.0 ?? right??

Comment: @VishwaRatna Yes

Answer (score 2):

Let's look closer at your function and what you try to test:

```java
URL myUrl = new URL("https://myUrl"); // (1)
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection(); // (2)
connection.connect(); // (3)

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); // (4)
String lastPacket = connection.getHeaderField("LastPacket");

byte fileContent[] = IOUtils.toByteArray((InputStream) connection.getInputStream()); // (5)

return fileContent;
```

So in line 1, 2 and 3 you create a connection object to some remote resource and connect to it. You use SDK's classes for that.

Then you check the response code (4) and read from the stream (5). Again, you are using SDK's standard library for that.

Question is: do you **really** want to unit test code that we are safe to assume **is working**?

What I would do is extract lines from 1 to 4 to a separate class with a method that returns a stream that you can read. And then, in your test mock that stream according to your needs. But don't unit test such low-level code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your preSetup is wrong as well.

Even though you mock HttpsURLConnection (httpsURLConnection) and URL (url), this isn't used in the test. 
You can't just use "url" (the mocked URL) in your test or setup, since in the method you want to test (myFunction), a new URL (myUrl) is created. This "myUrl" is not the same as "url" you mocked.

I would pass an URLConnection as an argument to that method (or create a second function). You then have full control over it and can mock it.

// Edit:
[Mocking a URL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565535/mocking-a-url-in-java)