# Mock an instance method call of another class that takes a URL and File object and writes a file to a HTTP connection

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to write UTs for a file called `DocumentStoreAccessor.java`. Here is the class below:

```
package com.company.main.accessor;

import com.company.main.dagger.component.AccessorComponent;
import com.company.main.dagger.component.DaggerAccessorComponent;
import com.company.main.util.aws.s3.AWSS3Util;

import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DocumentStoreAccessor {

    private final DocumentStore documentStoreClient; //Comes from Dagger

    
    public DocumentStoreAccessor() {
        AccessorComponent accessorComponent = DaggerAccessorComponent.create();
        this.documentStoreClient = accessorComponent.provideDocumentStoreClient();
  
    }

    private int putContentsIntoS3(CreateUploadS3UrlResult createUploadS3UrlResponse,
                                  @NonNull File file) {

        int uploadStatusCode = 0;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(createUploadS3UrlResponse.getS3Url());
            uploadStatusCode = new AWSS3Util().upload(url, file); //Instance comes from a util class

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return uploadStatusCode;
    }

    public String uploadFile(File file, DocumentFileExtension fileExtension) throws Exception {

        String documentId = null;
        CreateUploadS3UrlResult createUploadS3Urlresult = documentStoreClient.createUploadS3Url(new CreateUploadS3UrlRequest());
        int putContentsStatusCode = putContentsIntoS3(createUploadS3Urlresult, file);
        if (putContentsStatusCode == 200) {
            CreateDocumentRequest createDocumentRequest = new CreateDocumentRequest()       
            CreateDocumentResult document = documentStoreClient.createDocument(createDocumentRequest);
            documentId = document.getDocumentId();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Status code is: " + putContentsStatusCode);
        }
        return documentId;
    }
}
```

Inside this file I do `new AWSS3Util().upload(url, file)`.

And here is the `AWSS3Util.java`

```
package com.company.main.util.aws.s3;

import com.company.main.exception.DataAccessException;
import com.company.main.exception.RetriableDataAccessException;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AWSS3Util {

    private static final String PUT_REQUEST_METHOD = "PUT";

    public int upload(@NonNull final URL url, @NonNull final File file) throws IOException {

        final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        final Reader fileReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        int responseCode = 0;
        try {
            // Create the connection and use it to upload the new object using the pre-signed URL.
            connection = create(url);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod(PUT_REQUEST_METHOD);
            final OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String st;
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(st);
            }
            out.close();
            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RetriableDataAccessException(String.format("S3 upload request failed with request: %s", url.toString()), e);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
            fileReader.close();
            br.close();
        }
        return responseCode;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection create(URL url) throws IOException {
        return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }
}
```

I want to make `new AWSS3Util().upload(url, file)` return a `200`..

I'm unable to do so.. I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. Here is what I have for the past day:

```
package com.company.main.accessor;

import com.company.main.util.aws.s3.AWSS3Util;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DocumentStoreAccessorTest {

    @Mock
    private DocumentStore mockDocumentStoreClient;

    @Mock
    private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;

    @Mock
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    @InjectMocks
    private DocumentStoreAccessor classUnderTest;

    private URL url;
    private AWSS3Util awss3Util;
    private CreateUploadS3UrlRequest dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest;
    private CreateUploadS3UrlResult  dummyCreateUploadS3UrlResult;
    private CreateDocumentRequest dummyCreateDocumentRequest;
    private CreateDocumentResult dummyCreateDocumentResult;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws IOException {

        awss3Util = new AWSS3Util();

        url = getMockUrl(httpURLConnection);

        dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest = new CreateUploadS3UrlRequest();
        dummyCreateUploadS3UrlResult = new CreateUploadS3UrlResult().withS3Url("http://foo.io://:99");

        dummyCreateDocumentRequest = new CreateDocumentRequest();
        dummyCreateDocumentResult = new CreateDocumentResult().withDocumentId("foo");
    }


    @Test
    void uploadSuccess() throws IOException {


        when(mockDocumentStoreClient.createUploadS3Url(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest)).thenReturn(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlResult);
        AWSS3Util aSpy = Mockito.spy(awss3Util);
        Mockito.when(aSpy.upload(url, getDataToUpload())).thenReturn(200);

        when(mockDocumentStoreClient.createDocument(dummyCreateDocumentRequest)).thenReturn(dummyCreateDocumentResult);

        String id = classUnderTest.uploadFile(getDataToUpload(), DocumentFileExtension.XLSX);
        assertEquals(id, "foo");
        verify(mockDocumentStoreClient, times(1)).createUploadS3Url(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest);
    }

    private File getDataToUpload() {
        return new File("TestFileName.xlsx");
    }

    /**
     * We cannot directly use Mockito to mock URL. This helper method, helps us to create the mock url.
     * <p>
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565535/mocking-a-url-in-java
     */
    private URL getMockUrl(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection) throws IOException {
        final URLStreamHandler handler = new URLStreamHandler() {
            @Override
            protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL arg0)
                    throws IOException {
                return httpURLConnection;
            }
        };
        final URL url = new URL("http://foo.io", "foo.io", 80, "", handler);
        return url;
    }
}
```

- I'm unable to mock the URL class, so I followed a another Stackoverflow post..
- The `AWSS3Util` cannot come through Dagger, it is a util class that we're all using so this must not change.
- I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction.. I've tried "spying" on that `AWSS3Util` class. I want this method to return a 200 or any status code of my choice to cover them in UTs by asserting a String return as seen in the example below
- I can change the the `upload` method inside `AWSS3Util` to static if it helps UTs
- Cannot use PowerMockito (this is a last resort)

Try incorporating Yan's comments:

```
@Test
void verifyCreateUploadS3UrlInvocation() throws Exception {
    when(mockDocumentStoreClient.createUploadS3Url(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest)).thenReturn(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlResult);
    when(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(outputStream);
    when(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);


    when(awss3Util.upload(url, getDataToUpload())).thenReturn(200);

    when(mockDocumentStoreClient.createDocument(dummyCreateDocumentRequest)).thenReturn(dummyCreateDocumentResult);

    String id = classUnderTest.uploadFile(getDataToUpload(), DocumentFileExtension.XLSX);
    assertEquals(id, "foo");
    verify(mockDocumentStoreClient, times(1)).createUploadS3Url(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest);
}
```

I get a `405` thrown when I specifically want it to send a `200`, and therefore `java.lang.Exception: Status code is: 405` thrown from my function.

Comment: I didn't see that httpURLConnection mock has specified behivour during calling in AWSS3Util. I believe you need to specify what should be done when being executed methods of HttpURLConnection. After mocking HttpURLConnection behivour you can use real AWSS3Util and emulate uploading to server with mocked outputstream.

Comment: Hey, I've tried what you've asked - and I'm unable to force out a 200! Let me know if I've done it correctly - I've posted it above

Comment: I guess you shouldn't mock awss3Util:
when(awss3Util.upload(url, getDataToUpload())).thenReturn(200);

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to look at your OutputStream object. I would recommend to create byteArrayOutputStream, catch all bytes and check if these bytes equals to your real file bytes.

Comment: @Yan - In the tests, I do `awss3Util = new AWSS3Util();`. I don't mock it! The `405` is what you see above

Comment: @Yan Could you give me some sample code?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to violate the second rule - I had to DependencyInject it via Dagger

```
package com.company.main.dagger.module;

import com.company.main.util.aws.s3.AWSS3Util;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Module
public class AWSS3UtilModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public static AWSS3Util provideAwss3Util() {
        return new AWSS3Util();
    }
}
```

and then in my component

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ShipDocsDMSAccessorModule.class,
        AWSS3UtilModule.class
})
public interface AccessorComponent {
    ShipDocsDMS provideShipDocsDMSClient();
    AWSS3Util provideAwss3Util();
}
```

and then in my main class

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ShipDocsDMSAccessor {

    private final ShipDocsDMS shipDocsDMSClient;
    private final AWSS3Util awss3Util;

    public ShipDocsDMSAccessor() {
        AccessorComponent accessorComponent = DaggerAccessorComponent.create();
        this.shipDocsDMSClient = accessorComponent.provideShipDocsDMSClient();
        this.awss3Util = accessorComponent.provideAwss3Util();
    }
.
.
.
.
```

and then in my test, I can freely mock `AWSS3Util` dependency and carry ahead and force out the required response.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would change a little bit AWSS3Util, because reading binary files as string can lead to very interesting results.

```
import lombok.NonNull;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class AWSS3Util {

    private static final String PUT_REQUEST_METHOD = "PUT";

    public int upload(@NonNull final URL url, @NonNull final File file) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = create(url);
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod(PUT_REQUEST_METHOD);

            try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
            }

            return connection.getResponseCode();
        }
    }

    private HttpURLConnection create(URL url) throws IOException {
        return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }
}
```

Test for upload method could be like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertArrayEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        final HttpURLConnection mockUrlCon = mock(HttpURLConnection .class);
        URLStreamHandler stubUrlHandler = new URLStreamHandler() {
            @Override
            protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
                return mockUrlCon;
            }
        };
        URL url = new URL("http://foo.io", "foo.io", 80, "", stubUrlHandler);

        when(mockUrlCon.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        when(mockUrlCon.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(outputStream);

        File file = new File("c:\\anyFile.png");
        int responseCode = new AWSS3Util().upload(url, file);

        assertEquals(200, responseCode);

        byte[] expectedBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        byte[] actualBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        assertArrayEquals(expectedBytes, actualBytes);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Yan, thanks a lot for your efforts, but I'm trying to test `DocumentStoreAccessor` and not `AWSS3Util`. I need by `DocumentStoreAccessor`'s, `uploadFile(File file, DocumentFileExtension fileExtension)`, to return me a stringId by simulating a successful file upload, In this case, as shown in my question, I want it to return `foo` like I have mocked this dummy to return in my example above `dummyCreateDocumentResult = new CreateDocumentResult().withDocumentId("foo");`

Comment: I'm trying to test `classUnderTest.uploadFile(getDataToUpload(), DocumentFileExtension.XLSX);` to return be a String

Comment: Ops. sorry. I didn't get it. t would be great  to see the content of DocumentStoreAccessor class

Comment: I've posted a file called `DocumentStoreAccessor.java` right at the top. The other parts of it like `CreateUploadS3UrlRequest`, `CreateUploadS3UrlResult`, `CreateDocumentRequest`, `CreateDocumentResult` and `documentStoreClient` are classes from packages of other services that I don't write or own.

Comment: The one problem which has seen is that you specify another object for when scenario.         when(mockDocumentStoreClient.createUploadS3Url(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest)).thenReturn(dummyCreateUploadS3UrlResult);

But in DocumentStoreAccessor you have documentStoreClient.createUploadS3Url(new CreateUploadS3UrlRequest());

Comment: You can use `any()` instead of dummyCreateUploadS3UrlRequest, because DocumentStoreAccessor creates each time this request object. You need to pass as parameter or use `any()` with `when`

Comment: For me the issue is in mocking the function call inside `AWSS3Util()`, I'm unable to force out `200`